# What is the difference between atomic and non-capturing groups?

Tags: regex

1. What is an atomic group, (`(?>expr)`) and what is it used for?
   In https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html, the only example is when `expr` is alternation, such as the regex `a(?>bc|b)c` matches `abcc` but not `abc`. Are there examples with `expr` not being alternation?
2. Are atomic and non-capturing groups, (`(?:expr)`) the same thing?

Comment: Check the revision history on this post to see a link to the research this poster included where they also asked for an example to better understand the differences. The second revision seems to have invalidated [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936881/12695027)

Comment: Yes. While I appreciate that the edits make for a more succinct question, they change the question substantively and invalidate my answer as pointed out by Scratte. @double-beep, please reconsider the scope of your changes.

Comment: Not only that but the edit comment stating atomic groups are PCRE specific is clearly trash, for example... [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#atomic-groups) regexes support atomic groups

Answer (score 10):

1. When Atomic groups are used, the regex engine won't backtrack for further permutations if the complete regular expression has not been matched for a given string.

   Whenever you use an alternation, the regex will immediately try to match the rest of the expression if it is successful. Still, it will keep track of the position where other alternations are possible. If the rest of the expression is not matched, the regex will go back to the previously noted position and try the other combinations. If Atomic grouping *had* been used, the regex engine would *not* have kept track of the previous position and would just have given up matching.

   The above example doesn't explain the purpose of using atomic groups. It just demonstrates the elimination of backtracking. Atomic groups would be used in specific scenarios where greedy quantifiers are used, and further combinations are possible even though there is no alternation.
2. Atomic and non-capturing groups are different. Non-capturing groups don't save the matches' value, while atomic groups disable backtracking if further combinations are needed.

For example, the regular expression `a(?:bc|b)c` matches both `abcc` and `abc` (without capturing the match), whilst `a(?>bc|c)c` only matches `abcc`. If the regex was `a(?>b|bc)c`, it would only match `abc`, whilst `a(?:b|bc)c` would still match both.

Comment: Don't forget, Atomic groups are non-capturing too!

Answer (score 6):

Atomic groups (and the [possessive modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)) are useful to avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) - which can be exploited by malicious users to trigger denial of service attacks by gobbling up a server's memory.

Non-capturing groups are just that -- non-capturing. The regex engine can backtrack into a non-capturing group; not into an atomic group.

Comment: Thanks! What differences are between atomic groups and the possessive modifier? Are they for the identical purposes?

Comment: The possessive modifier is just syntactic sugar for atomic: `(?:a|b)*+` is equivalent to `(?>(?:a|b)*)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there examples with `expr` not being alternation?

Consider the following pattern:

```
(abc)?a
```

This finds a match in both `abc` and `abca`. But what happens when the optional part becomes atomic?

```
(?>(abc)?)a
```

It no longer finds a match in `abc`. It will never give up `abc`, so the final `a` fails.

As others have said, there are other situations where you might want to avoid backtracking, even if it has no effect on the final match, to optimise your regex.

Comment: Kindly note that the quote in this post came from the Question. See the first revision of the Question to understand what's going on here.