# Use of ?> in Logstash Grok patterns

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Several of the standard [Logstash Grok patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.0/patterns/grok-patterns) use the `?>` syntax, which I've never seen in a regex and doesn't seem to be standard syntax.

Example for a UNIXPATH:

```
(?>/(?>[\w_%!$@:.,-]+|\\.)*)+
```

What does the use of `?>` mean? Is it some kind of weird lookahead?

Comment: I fail to find a case where it would be different from `(?>\/[\w_%!$@:.,-]*)+`

Comment: Good point... I didn't write this though, it's from the Grok documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It's an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it, automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group

I don't see any motivation to use it in your case, apart making the regex faster (assuming it wasn't possible to simply have a start of string anchor for the external one, and removing the + after the  character range would probably be a better solution for the internal one).

Comment: I'm assuming that neither ?: nor ?> is applied recursively to nested groups? Otherwise there'd be no reason that the standard UNIXPATH filter I mentioned would use ?> twice...

Answer (score 2):

It is standard for .NET, PCRE, and many other regex engines. However, not available in JavaScript.

From an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6489053/3832970):

> Atomic groups (and the [possessive modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)) are useful to avoid
>   [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) - which can be exploited by malicious users
>   to trigger denial of service attacks by gobbling up a server's memory.

[When are Atomic Groups Important?](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic)

> When a series of characters only makes sense as a block, using an
>   atomic group can prevent needless backtracking. This is explored on
>   the section on possessive quantifiers. In such situations atomic
>   quantifiers can be useful, but not necessarily mission-critical.
>
> On the other hand, there are situations where atomic quantifiers can
>   save your pattern from disaster. They are particularly useful:
>
> ✽ In order to avoid the [Lazy Trap](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazytrap) with patterns that contain lazy
>   quantifiers whose token can eat the delimiter
>  ✽ To avoid certain forms
>   of the [Explosive Quantifier Trap](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html)

Comment: BTW, the regex you showed also works well with non-capturing groups, try replacing `?>` with `?:` on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sC8dO8/1).